# Output from 'ls' differs when in root mode

Tags: root

When I use the command `sudo -i` and input the password, and then input `ls`, I found that I can only see the Desktop folder and packages in terminal.

But when I came back to normal mode, all the folder showed up.

I don't know what cause this problem...Can someone help me ?

Comment: If you want your home directory while `root` you have to do `cd /home/user/Desktop`

Comment: Oh my god...Thanks! Your answer solve my problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sudo -i` command gives you a shell as root, and you will be in the `root` user's home directory, not your own. As `root` is not generally a user you should use normally, only very few files will exist in the home directory for that user, particularly the skeleton directory structure for any new user.

Answer (score 3):

It is because when you are in root mode you are in root's home directory. Try this:

```
pwd
sudo -i
pwd
```

You will see the directory change

Answer (score 1):

this was troubling me too much also, so I made this script:

```
params="$@";sudo -i bash -c "cd \"`pwd`\";$params"
```

`pwd` will be run with your normal user, before the command you want

put it on a script file which is `root:root rw-r--r--` on a folder full hierarchy owned by root too like `/MyScripts` (create it) to be safer..

the flaw on it is if you have a parameter with a space in-between like `ls -1 a "b c"`, would require to be `ls -1 a "b\ c"`, but this can be worked out later when you improve the script :)